# Postgres check if row exists before inserting

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have the following table

| id | customerNumber | productId | dateTime | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 12 | NA | 2018-11-04 14:55:16.000000 | active |
| 1 | 12 | NA | 2018-11-03 13:51:08.000000 | active |

The problem I have is that every time an action is registered, a new insert with a new row is created which I don't need. Over time this table fills up.

```
INSERT INTO db.table("customerNumber", "productId", "dateTime", "action") 
VALUES (:customerNumber, :productId, (now() at time zone ('utc')), :action);
```

So what I want to instead is to write a new query that follows the following criteria:

1. If the row does not exist, insert a new one.
2. If a single row exists with the customer number, update the values.
3. If multiple rows exists with the same `customerNumber`, then only the one with the latest `dateTime` should be updated.

In the table above for example, the first row with id == 2 should be updated only.

I have done some searching and testing. Many seem to refer to using the conflict operation, but this will not work since `customerNumber` is not unique here. How can I make this happen within a single query?

Comment: If you want to have a single row for each `customerNumber`, then add a UNIQUE constraint on that column and use UPSERT.

Comment: Sadly, I am not in a position to change keys or constraints as this is activly used.

Comment: If you have such an artificial restriction, then you'll need to synchronize the changes using row locks or using the SERIALIZABLE isolation level to avoid race conditions. Then: 1) check for the existence of the row and 2) update or insert the row accordingly.

Comment: You may not be in a position to change constraints, but if you want valid advice you must at least disclose your current table definition. Show a complete `CREATE TABLE` statement incl all constraints, and existing indexes. And always your version of Postgres. Also, why not delete old, duplicate entries before (or during) the switch to your new workflow.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With inspiration of @Daqs answer and chatGpt, I got this working;

```
WITH updatedvalues_row AS (
    UPDATE db.table
    SET productId = :productId, dateTime = (now() at time zone 'utc'), action = :action
    WHERE (customerNumber, dateTime) = (
        SELECT customerNumber, MAX(dateTime) as dateTime
        FROM db.table
        WHERE customerNumber = :customerNumber
        GROUP BY customerNumber
    )
    RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO db.table("customerNumber", "productId", "dateTime", "action")
SELECT :customerNumber, :productId, (now() at time zone 'utc'), :action
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM updatedvalues_row);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to solve the issue that you have:You can use CTE to solve the following query and the query is as follows:

```
WITH updatedvalues_row AS (
     UPDATE db.table
     SET productId = :productId, dateTime = (now() at time zone ('utc')), 
     action = :action
         WHERE customerNumber = :customerNumber
         ORDER BY dateTime DESC
         LIMIT 1
         RETURNING *
    )
    INSERT INTO db.table("customerNumber", "productId", "dateTime", "action")
    SELECT :customerNumber, :productId, (now() at time zone ('utc')), :action
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM updated_row);
```

The above query using the CTE expression will first attempt to update the first row with the matching `customerNumber` and the latest `dateTime`.

If a row is updated, it returns the updated row's data.

If no row matches the criteria, it returns an empty result.

Lastly insert a new row only if the updatedvalues_row CTE returned no rows

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it says ORDER is not valid.
operator>, AT, ISNULL, NOTNULL, OPERATOR, RETURNING, TIME, WITH or '[' expected, got 'ORDER'

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you can structure your query:

- Check if the row exists
- Update if a single row exists
- Update the row with the latest dateTime

```
    INSERT INTO db.table ("customerNumber", "productId", "dateTime", "action") 
    VALUES (:customerNumber, :productId, (now() at time zone 'utc'), :action)
    ON CONFLICT ("customerNumber") DO 
    UPDATE 
    SET "productId" = :productId, 
        "dateTime" = (now() at time zone 'utc'), 
        "action" = :action
    WHERE db.table.id = (
        SELECT id FROM db.table 
        WHERE "customerNumber" = :customerNumber 
        ORDER BY "dateTime" DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    );
```

To perform this operation within a single query, you can use the `SQL MERGE` statement.

Comment: I dont think CONFLICT will work since customerNumber is not the primary key and thus not unique as you can see in my example.